Serving static files directly in Google App Engine with express
I have a standard Google App Engine environment and am trying to serve some static files for my create-react-app frontend, but I'm not able to do so without copying over the client/build/ files into the server/ folder.
My file structure looks like this:
.
├── app.yaml
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── client
│   ├── build/
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public/
│   ├── src/
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── server
    ├── dist/
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── src/
    └── tsconfig.json


What I had been doing is uploading all the source files to Google Cloud (and excluding the locally-built ones), letting it build everything in the cloud, and then at the end of the build process copying across the client files over to the server:
"build": "npm run build:client && npm run build:server && rsync -av --delete client/build/ server/build/"
but it seemed unnecessary to build files in the client and then copy them to the server.
I was thinking I'd use handlers in app.yaml to directly serve the static files from client/, based on the example here but also allowing my server to handle API requests. When I tried this, I added the following to app.yaml:
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: client/build/static

  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|js))$
    static_files: client/build/\1
    upload: client/build/.*\.(json|ico|js)$

  - url: /.*
    script: auto

and changed my routes in app.ts slightly:
// Routes
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
...

// Serve the React app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../client/build', 'index.html')); // before it was just '../build' instead
});

but this meant that I got a 404 error whenever trying to access the frontend.
Is the correct approach simply to copy across the built files from client/ to server/? If so, is there a reason for this, and is it better to do it locally or as part of the build step in the cloud? Otherwise, what do I need to change about the handlers or routing for it to work?

Do you want to serve your file from App Engine or from your server? If from App Engine, only redirect from a URL, if it's from your code, you must collocate your server code and your static files.

@guillaumeblaquiere Sorry, not sure I completely understand your distinction between serving from App Engine or the server. My server (i.e. the file in ./server/dist/server.js) is what's being run in App Engine. What do you mean about redirecting from a URL?

Sorry for that. You have 2 solutions: Either you deploy your static files on App Engine, you configure a router (dispatch) to serve them automatically (behind the scene, you have a kind of NGINX that serve your file on a given URL). Or you can deploy your own server (Python for instance) and serve your file directly from your code; this option requires (a few) CPU resource to execute Python and serve the data, instead of letting App Engine doing it automatically for you (and for free!)

@guillaumeblaquiere Thanks! To clarify, I want to serve the files from within App Engine, the question is about the appropriate file structure to enable it to do that: why is my attempt to use GAE to serve static files when they're located in client/build not working, but it does work when I serve those same files after being copied by GAE into server/build?

After you run your build for the client, do you see a folder in the build directory called static? If you don't, then your 404 error is expected because according to the first handler in your app.yaml, you're telling Google to look in the path client > build > static whenever it sees a url that starts with /static

@NoCommandLine yes, at least locally when I run the build there's a ./client/build/static/ folder (I think it's not easily possible to see the file structure in GCP itself?).

Older version of the documentation says

All files in this directory are uploaded with your app as static files. App Engine stores and serves static files separately from your app's files.

Newer version of the documentation says

All of the files in the given directory are uploaded as static files

From the above two statements, I believe Google will look for files in client/build/static during your deploy and treat them as static (it will probably store them somewhere else separate from your app files). But you don't have such a folder (static) before/during your deploy. The folder is only created after you run the build command which you say you're running in production (after production).
Since you say that running a build locally creates the static folder, you can try running your build locally and then deploying the built versions of your server and client. This also means that you have to remove the build script in your package.json or follow the steps here.
